# Using an Ampersand in jquery ajax request

Tags: jquery, special-characters

I have form inputs in a table row, which I would like to submit via ajax.

```
$(this).closest("tr").find("input,select,textarea").each(function(){$data+=$(this).attr('name')+'='+encodeURIComponent($(this).val())+'&';
```

I had everything working fine - until one of the inputs had an ampersand in the value.  I found some information on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226480/ampersand-character-inside-a-value-of-jquery-ajax-request-data-option), which helped a lot - and using encodeURIComponent (as shown above) I was able to get the form to submit without a problem.  My question is - in that post, @T.J. Crowder mentioned how he would "strongly recommend" using @Darin Dimitrov's solution:

```
data: { id: thisId, value: thisValue }
```

How would I implement this in my current code?  Also - is there any benefit to using the second code, or is encodeURIComponent just as good?

Comment: Dude... use [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: I tried using serialize, - such as $data=$('#IDofTR').serialize(); but it kept returning a blank value. I assumed it was because my fields aren't in a form, but a tr.

Comment: @prodigitalson ... Not what the OP was asking... -1

Comment: Ahhh well in that cas use a hash instead of trying to make a string.. much easier to manage.

Comment: @prodigitalson Why a hash instead of an object literal?

Comment: sorry daniel.. when i say hash i mean object literal ie. `{}`.

Comment: @prodigitalson - I'm not familiar with using hashes / object literals. Is that what is referenced above in Darin Dimitrov's solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the native Javascript "Object" pseudo-class. I don't really understand your code's purpose; but, supossing it is correct, should look like this:

```
$data = new Object;
$(this).closest("tr").find("input,select,textarea").each(function(){
  $data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked well. Do you know if there are any inherent benefits to using this code over my original - other than code brevity?

Comment: You should, when posible, always use native classes and objects, this tends to be faster and more easy to implement than crude strings.